# Как центрировать по вертикали блок в изображении?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как центрировать блок `container` по вертикали в родителе `header`?

У меня не получается центрировать из-за того, что высота блока `header` меняется относительно размера экрана.

Посоветуйте, что можно сделать.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.nav {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.container {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dashed #777;
  position: relative;
}

.container:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  content: "Container";
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
 <div class="header">
<img src="https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/coffee_cup_hands_120722_2560x1080.jpg">
 <div class="nav">
 <span>Text-1</span>
 <span>Text-2</span>
 <span>Text-3</span>
 <span>Text-4</span>
 <span>Text-5</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 Stack Overflow
</div>
 </div>
```

*Рекомендую запустить код на всё страницу.*

Comment: 1. под высотой хедера вы подразумеваете высоту картинки? 2. высота хардовая или чем то определяется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,body,.header {min-height:100%;height:100%;} /* предполагаем: вы имели в виду, что шапка растягивается как минимум на всю высоту экрана, иначе по высоте она равна высоте блока .container, что всегда делает его расположенным строго по центру родителя */

.header img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.nav {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.container {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dashed #777;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%; /* опускаем на 50% высоты родителя */
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* поднимаем на 50% собственной высоты */
}

.container:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  content: "Container";
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
 <div class="header">
<img src="https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/coffee_cup_hands_120722_2560x1080.jpg">
 <div class="nav">
 <span>Text-1</span>
 <span>Text-2</span>
 <span>Text-3</span>
 <span>Text-4</span>
 <span>Text-5</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
 Stack Overflow
</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.nav {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.container {
  /*изменения в коде*/
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /*изменения в коде*/
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dashed #777;
  position: relative;
}

.container:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  content: "Container";
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/coffee_cup_hands_120722_2560x1080.jpg">
  <div class="nav">
    <span>Text-1</span>
    <span>Text-2</span>
    <span>Text-3</span>
    <span>Text-4</span>
    <span>Text-5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    Stack Overflow
  </div>
</div>
```